# Replace a foreach loop with XPath expression using DOMXPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, foreach, domxpath

I want to replace a foreach loop using a xpath expression, but I need that a DOMXPath object to return more than one list.

I have the following XML (simplified) and I using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php) to iterate over it:

```
<a:RoomsType>
    <a:Rooms>
      <a:Room>
          <a:RPH>0</a:RPH>
      </a:Room>
      <a:Room>
          <a:RPH>1</a:RPH>
      </a:Room>
      <a:Room>
          <a:RPH>2</a:RPH>
      </a:Room>
      <a:Room>
          <a:RPH>0</a:RPH>
      </a:Room>
    <a:Rooms>
<a:RoomsType>
```

I want to split the rooms by the RPH number, creating a list of rooms for each RPH number. Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
 //$xpath is a DOMXPath object
 $roomsToIterate = $this->xpath->query("//a:RoomsType/a:Rooms/a:Room");

 $roomList = array();
 foreach ($roomsToIterate as $room) {
     $rphCandidate = $room->getElementsByTagName("RPH")->item(0)->nodeValue;
     if (!isset($roomList[$rphCandidate])) {
         $roomList[$rphCandidate] = array();
     }
     $roomList[$rphCandidate][] = $room;
 }
```

This is working for now, but I want to replace the foreach loop with a Xpath expression. I can use the expression `$rooms = $this->xpath->query("//a:RoomsType/a:Rooms/a:Room[a:RPH='{$rph}']");` with `$rph` being a number, but how can I do it if I don't know the RPH (it could be anything between 0 and 99). Is it possible?

In short, Are there any way to replace my foreach loop using XPath?

I was thinking about the use of [registerPhpFunctions](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php) and a custom function, but I concerned about the performance of this approach compared with foreach loop

Comment: No you will still need an `foeach`. You have to iterate the rooms to created the nested result or the possible $rph values to fetch the groups.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, I was right on my original approach. I'll keep this question open for any new idea of improvement, but you can post your comment as an answer, if you want. If I don't receive any new suggestions, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath 1.0 expression will return a list of nodes, they can to some extend flatten an existing structure if you use an axis like `descendant` or `ancestor`, but it will be a list of nodes. It can not group or aggregate them.

You could fetch a lists of nodes with a specific `RPH` value. But you would need to this for each value, the result would be another loop. This would mean to fetch all `RPH` values, make them unique, iterate them and execute and Xpath expression for each value.

Your current solution is fine.